# How can I define an optional subpath with Rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am trying to package a Vue app under a Rocket served path (under `/admin`). I have written the following matchers:

```
#[get("/admin/<path..>")]
fn admin_panel(_admin: AdminUser, path: Option<PathBuf>) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    match path {
        Some(admin_path) => match NamedFile::open(Path::new("admin/").join(admin_path)).ok() {
            Some(admin_file) => Some(admin_file),
            // if the file is not found, we fallback onto admin/index.html, so the client routing can kick in
            None => NamedFile::open(Path::new("admin/index.html")).ok()
        },
        None => NamedFile::open(Path::new("admin/index.html")).ok()
    }
}

#[get("/admin/<_path..>", rank = 2)]
fn admin_panel_user(_user: AuthenticatedUser, _path: Option<PathBuf>) -> &'static str {
    "Sorry, you must be an administrator to access this page."
}

#[get("/admin/<_path..>", rank = 3)]
fn admin_panel_redirect(_path: Option<PathBuf>) -> Redirect {
    Redirect::to(uri!(login::login))
}
```

However, with this, when I try to access `/admin`, I get a 404. I need to create a new route with only "/admin" and redirect to `/admin/index.html`, but this is not ideal.

I thought that defining the `PathBuf` as an `Option` would make it optional, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I make the request matcher work for when the request both has, and does not have a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a functionality not yet supported by Rocket. The possibility of adding it has been discussed [in this PR on Github](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/985) to work in a similar way to what I was expecting.

For now, the solution is to do something like the posted example:

```
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> String {
    everything(None)
}
#[get("/<path..>")]
fn everything(path: Option<PathBuf>) -> String {
    format!("{:?}", path)
}
```